# How to remember invited friends to Facebook app?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm creating game for Facebook, here is `Invite friends` function.

For now If user invite friend, after It close and open invite box friend appears on the list again. I need that app remembered which friends are already invited and they should not appear on list.

For now my code looks like:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<a href="#" onclick="FbRequest('This page is amazing, check it out!','4d5da07acbbb0');"><center>Invite Friends</center></a>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () {


window.onload =FbRequest('This page is amazing, check it out!','4d5da07acbbb0');
}
function FbRequest(message, data){
        FB.ui({method:'apprequests',message:message,data:data,title:'Share this site with your friends'},
                function(response){
                        // response.request_ids holds an array of user ids that received the request
                }
        );
}

// typical application initialization code for your site
(function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    e.async = true;
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId   : '00000000',
        session : {},
        status   : true,
        cookie  : true,
        xfbml   : true
    });
};

</script>
```

I'm useing code example and here is commented line: `// response.request_ids holds an array of user ids that received the request` maybe this is what I need just I don't know how to use It correctly.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need a way to persist the request information. If you have a backend service provider (i.e. a web server running php and mysql), you could send the requested id's to your server for storing in the database via ajax. If you don't have a backend service provider, you're only other option is client side storage such as "local storage" which should be regarded as volatile.
2. At some point before the `app request` dialog is called, you need to get a list of the id's you have previously sent to, from the storage device implemented in step 1 above. I guess it depends on how your game is loaded, but there are a lot of ways of doing this. If your page is generated dynamically in php for example, you could dump a javascript array of all the id's into the HTML output.

   A nicer way might be to pop-up a spinner with "please wait...", ajax to get the id's already sent to, and then in your ajax callback function, close the spinner pop-up and call the facebook specific function with your list of exclusion id's.
3. And [here in the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/) you can see the `exclude_ids` parameter you need to fill.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I would like to use mysql database. 
I'm useing code example and here is commented line: `// response.request_ids holds an array of user ids that received the request` maybe this is what I need just I don't know how to use It correctly. So after successfully write user id's to database how correctly create new list without these id's? Thank you.

Comment: As per step 2 and 3. You need to retrieve the id's from the database either on page load and write them as a javascript array in the html output. Or use AJAX to get the id's before opening the facebook dialog. The `exclude_ids` parameter in the linked documentation shows how to pass them to facebook

Comment: Thank ou for answer, could you give me example how code should look like?